# Find title attribute in an array and apply class only to that particular lightning:button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a javascript array with values

```
arr1 = ["176820","176770","176771","176773"].
```

I want to loop over the above array values to find the title attribute of a lightning:button in the above array and if it exists then apply a class 'blueicn.

Below is my code

```
<lightning:button class="greyicn" aura:id="Favorite1" title="{!v.document.id}"
      iconName="utility:favorite"
      type="submit"
      variant="base"
      onclick="{!c.addfavorite}"
    />
```

Please help me on this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in template markup to tell if a value matches any value in an array of values.

You will need an attribute to tell which value should be used:

```
<aura:attribute name="buttonStyle" type="String" default="greyicn" />
<lightning:button class="{!v.buttonStyle}" aura:id="Favorite1" title="{!v.document.id}"
```

You will then need to set the `buttonStyle` attribute depending on your conditions.

Comment: Actually I have a requirement to set the records as favorite on a button click as shown in below image.

I have an array which contains the title attribute values of all those favorites which are currently checked( with class='blueicn').

But my challenge is like when i'm clicking on Previous/Next, the checked stars are getting unchecked and basically not retaining the value.

Hence i want to put the blueicn class on all the buttons where title attributes contains in this array.

I have just added the screenshot of the stars in my initial question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add any update explaining what you are trying to do and what you have tried for yourself.

Comment: @PravindraSingh This is a variant of [this code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/88mc3Gx8E4OZNksS14kZ/src/app.css?p=stories), which provides a way to preserve selections across pages.