# Apply CSS on lightning:button based on array of indexes

Tags: aura, array

I have a group of lightning:button icons on my aura component inside a data table.
I want to apply a custom css on some of them based on the array of indexes i have.

Below is my lightning:button code.

<lightning:button
aura:id="Favorite1"
title="{!v.document.id}"
iconName="utility:favorite"
type="submit"
variant="base"
onclick="{!c.addfavorite}"
/>

And the array of indexes in an aura attribute 'component.get("v.IndexofFavDocuments")'.

How can i iterate over these indexes, fetch the aura:ids of those specific buttons and apply a custom css 'blueicn'.

Please help me out on this.
I can go by this approach only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an aura:id can't be dynamically set. Forget about aura:id to find something in an iterator. And I didn't get why you have a title {!v.document.id} in your button. Would you not rather refer to the item that you iterate on here (which makes it wrong to refer to the value provider "v")?

In any case - let's assume you have a Lightning table styled according to the Lightning design system; you have some rows and in each row buttons; in some of these rows you want to apply the CSS class blueicn to a button, depending on an attribute "Colour" of the document item referred to by that particular row.

Your button could have this class attribute:

```
class="{!document.Colour=='BLUE'?'blueicn':''}"
```

Helpful?!

Comment: Thank you Felix for your response.

Actually i have an array of indexes in an attribute 'v.IndexofFavDocuments'.

Basically I want to iterate over this array by lightning:button name attribute, and if it matches then fetch that aura:id and apply this class.

Below is my lightning:button on each row.

<lightning:button
      aura:id="Favorite1"                
      title="{!v.document.id}"
      iconName="utility:favorite"
      type="submit"
      variant="base"
      onclick="{!c.addfavorite}"
      name="{!v.index}"                
    />

Please help.

Comment: Based on which event would you "fetch that aura:id and apply this class"? Why not apply the class during component rendering? As you insist on using the aura:id, let me ask: Are you aware that you'd get an array of buttons with the aura:id "Favorite1", if you retrieve-by-aura-id in your component? As many buttons as you have rows! (It would be better, if you improve your original question above instead of providing details in comments.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you're stuck is because what you're trying to do is not possible. There is no [expression function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) that allows to you see if a value is contained in a list of values. I stated as much in my previous answer to your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/365914/2984).

What you need to do is place the desired class inside the data, like this:

```
<lightning:button title="{!document.id}" 
  class="{!document.style}"
  data-id="{!document.id}"
  iconName="utility:favorite" 
  onclick="{!c.addfavorite}" />
```

Which you then set for each document:

```
const indexes = component.get("v.IndexofFavDocuments")
const documents = [...component.get("v.documents")];
documents.forEach(document => {
  document.style = indexes.indexOf(document.id) > -1? 'class1':'class2'
});
component.set("v.documents", documents);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir